# How to turn string that stores number operations into numbers and then get a result in kotlin

Tags: string, kotlin, numbers, calculator

i have a string like
`var string = "5+7+10"`

is there a way to turn this into a double and add them all up and get

`var double = 22.0`

i tried to store operators and numbers in seperate variables but it still does not work when i try to add them up

Comment: If you want to support other arithmetic operators too (as per a deleted comment), then you'll probably need a proper parser — especially if you want to support full operator precedence/ordering, brackets, etc. You could write one yourself (it's a very good exercise, though probably a bit advanced for you right now, and certainly beyond a SO question) or there are doubtless libraries you can use.

Answer (score 0):

You can not turn that to a double as a whole. But if you split the elements and take them one by one, you can do it:

```
    var string = "5+7+10"
    val array: List<String> = string.split("+")
    var sumDouble: Double = 0.0
    for (element in array) {
        sumDouble += java.lang.Double.parseDouble(element)
    }
    println(sumDouble.toString())
```

This will give you sumDouble = 22.0 as a double.

Answer (score 0):

Using Kotlin Spirit library
https://github.com/tiksem/KotlinSpirit

```
val r = double % '+'
r.compile().parseGetResultOrThrow("5+13.4+6").sum()
```